# Typescript: Merge types of similar keys in a composed type

Tags: typescript

A generated type gives me:

```
type Result = {
  common: string;
} & ({ propA: number; propB: null } | { propA: null; propB: string });
```

Basically, `propA` and `propB` are part of a `oneOf`. Either `propA` or `propB` can be defined but they can't be both defined at the same time.

This is very useful in some part of my code.

Now, I need create a new type based on that one that'd give me:

```
{
  common: string;
  propA: number | null;
  propB: string | null;
}
```

I need to be able in another part of my code to define them all and potentially set `propA` and `propB` at the same time. I have tried to "trick" TS compiler in different ways... Without any success!

First here are some helpers I've got:

```
type Diff<T, U> = T extends U ? never : T;
type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T];
```

And now here are the different pieces of code I tried:

```
type Inline<T> = {[key in keyof T]: T[key]}
type Inline<T> = {[key in keyof T]: ValueOf<Pick<T, key>>}
type Inline<T> = {[key in keyof T]: T[Diff<keyof T, Exclude<keyof T, key>> ]}
```

But nothing to do. TS always manages to get back on his feet and put back the original `{ propA: number; propB: null } | { propA: null; propB: string }`

Is this even possible? I hope so, please tell me I'm missing something, thanks!

Comment: `{[P in keyof Result]: Result[P]}` [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAShDOBXANsKBeKBvAsAKCkIGMB7AWzJIDsAuKeYAJwEsqBzAbnwF8oAyKAAosUMIxJgAgnSqIyAIwiMOo8WABCMlMii8APtlUTpUWcmQqxEzfSas2ugJRc8+UJCgBZJWwgATDEMAbQAFKFYoAGsIEBIAM1gEFGAAXTo4JFRQlN0gA)

Comment: Thanks Aluan, that's exactly what I want but I was wondering if it's possible to do that only using generics?

Comment: Can you clarify? There is already a generic `Pick<T, K extends keyof T>` that does the same: `Pick<Result, keyof Result>` if that's what you mean... somehow I think you want something else.

Comment: Your initial comment works great, but it's not something I can reuse like `Pick` for example. I'd like to have one generic to do that, except that as soon as I try to do that I come back to my initial issue

Comment: I know I'm not clear sorry it's a very hard one to explain for me :/

Comment: Would this work? `type Inline<T> = Pick<T, keyof T>`?

Comment: Holy coooow you're right!!! It works, I'd never have figured that out this way! Thanks a lot, please post it as an answer and I'll accept it :)

Comment: Glad to help. I will try to add an answer, but I am not exactly sure what the correct language to describe this is. I think it is eagerly evaluating generic instantiation or something like that...

Comment: I'm not sure either ha. I did struggle so much to write the question... If you find I'd be happy to know! If you don't just post the code it's already super nice even though I'm curious to know how to name this!